# Glossary-like list of subsection headings

Tags: sectioning, titles, glossaries

I have a document, that has same subsection headings on multiple pages. I would like to create something like a glossary, that prints the list of headings and references to the pages where the headings are. I can do this with `glossaries` package, but I have to define `\newglossaryentry` with empty description for each heading, which I would like to avoid (it is quite annoying for a lot of headings). Is there any better way to do this? (It doesn't have to use glossaries, I don't care...)

This does basically what I want with glossaries, which seems overly complicated to me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{heading1}
{
  name=heading1,
  description={},
}
\newglossaryentry{heading2}
{
  name=heading2,
  description={},
}

\begin{document}
\printglossaries
\clearpage

\section{sth}
\subsection{\Gls{heading1}}
...
\subsection{\Gls{heading2}}
\lipsum
\subsection{\Gls{heading2}}
\lipsum
\subsection{\Gls{heading1}}
...

\end{document}
```

Comment: this would be entirely manual, but it should give you an acceptable result.  give each of your subsections a `\label`.  then treat your "list of subsection headings" as a `\chapter*`.  within that, prepare a table of the subheading names, and follow each one with a list of `\pageref{<label>}`s.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `index` package option, it will define the `\newterm` command where you can just do `\newterm{heading1}`, but this will put all the terms in the new `index` glossary instead of the `main` (default) glossary. So you could either use this option and just change the glossary title or define a command like `\newterm` that uses the `main` glossary instead of the `index` glossary.

**Method 1:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[index,nomain]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newterm{heading1}
\newterm{heading2}

\begin{document}
\printindex[title={Glossary}]
\clearpage

\section{sth}
\subsection{\Gls{heading1}}
...
\subsection{\Gls{heading2}}
\lipsum
\subsection{\Gls{heading2}}
\lipsum
\subsection{\Gls{heading1}}
...

\end{document}
```

**Method 2:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newcommand*{\newterm}[2][]{%
\newglossaryentry{#2}%
{name={#2},description={\nopostdesc},#1}}

\newterm{heading1}
\newterm{heading2}

\begin{document}
\printglossaries
\clearpage

\section{sth}
\subsection{\Gls{heading1}}
...
\subsection{\Gls{heading2}}
\lipsum
\subsection{\Gls{heading2}}
\lipsum
\subsection{\Gls{heading1}}
...

\end{document}
```

*Edit:* Be aware of the [problems associated with using commands like `\Gls` in section headings](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/faq.cgi?action=view&categorylabel=glossaries#movingarg).

Comment: Thanks, but this still makes me define `\newterm{heading}` for each heading I use. Which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry I didn't realise you didn't want any commands in the heading. Perhaps an easier solution would be to parse the `.toc` file. Maybe create a `makeindex` style that can read `\contentsline` with the third argument as the location.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.aux` file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\glssubsection}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{@glssubsection\detokenize{#1}}
    {\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newglossaryentry{#1}{name=#1,description={}}}%
     \global\@namedef{@glssubsection\detokenize{#1}}{}}{}%
  \ifglsentryexists{#1}
    {\subsection{\texorpdfstring{\Gls{#1}}{#1}}}%
    {\subsection{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\printglossaries
\clearpage

\section{sth}
\glssubsection{heading1}
\lipsum
\glssubsection{heading2}
\lipsum
\glssubsection{heading2}
\lipsum
\glssubsection{heading1}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

I leave to you the formatting of the glossary.

Comment: How does this work? I'm getting `! Package glossaries Error: Glossary entry 'heading1' has not been defined.` error, If I try to build the example. Thanks.

Comment: @Jaa-c Sorry, I used the wrong command; now it's fixed.